# how to add HDFS path in log4j.properties

Tags: hadoop, properties, log4j, hdfs, oozie

i have a properties file in my maven project
i am generating some log files while the MR code is running

### so in properties file i had this ::

log4j.appender.debugLog.File=/home/bigdata/Downloads/log1

so it worked and generated log files on this path

but i want this files to bee generated on HDFS

### so i changed the path to this ::

log4j.appender.debugLog.File=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/bigdata/WCWF/log1

now when im running the program, it is executing fine but not generating log files on this HDFS path

need help please !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write Log4j output to HDFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420170/write-log4j-output-to-hdfs)

Comment: I don't understand what you expected to happen here... 1) can log4j write files across network protocols? 2) log4j would need to know how to parse all uri schemas if it could 3) If it did work, that would crash immediately if the directory existed on HDFS

Comment: nope ! see , what flume does is collect the data from different sources and put in central storage
what i want is....the output files should be stored in hdfs
same way it stored in local file system
i just want it to store on hdfs path
like this :: ${namenode}/a/b/c/...
but its not working :s

Comment: Actually, Flume takes files from point A to point B. HDFS isn't necessary, but it can do exactly what you said. Look at the flume documentation for a spooling directory source (input), file channel (transport layer), and HDFS sink (output)

Comment: it looks like what i wanted 
tnx fro help cricket_007